# How to delete entire rows if it has duplicates values and ids in the data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Hello all  my df looks like

```
PID Record date category
123 22-04-1996   2
123 25-02-2000   NA
132 16-06-1994   1
143 25-07-1990   3
154 09-07-1993   1
154 08-08-1998   2
165 23-03-1993   NA
165 15-05-1995   NA
174 30-12-2000   NA
```

If category value is available in any of one rows for same PID i want to remove them from the dataframe
completely.

Expected output :

```
PID Record date category
132 16-06-1994   1
143 25-07-1990   3
165 23-03-1993   NA
165 15-05-1995   NA
174 30-12-2000   NA
```

Thank You in Advance

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to do this the other way around and delete any PID value that appears more than once?

Comment: if I have understood correctly, rows should not be deleted when is.na(category).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `{dplyr}` you can group your data by `PID` and maintain only groups with a single distinct value of `category` (`NA` included).

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union


example_data <- tribble(
    ~PID, ~`Record date`, ~category,
     123,   "22-04-1996",     2,
     123,   "25-02-2000",     NA,
     132,   "16-06-1994",     1,
     143,   "25-07-1990",     3,
     154,   "09-07-1993",     1,
     154,   "08-08-1998",     2,
     165,   "23-03-1993",     NA,
     165,   "15-05-1995",     NA,
     174,   "30-12-2000",     NA
)

example_data %>% 
    with_groups(PID, filter, n_distinct(category) == 1)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>     PID `Record date` category
#>   <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>
#> 1   132 16-06-1994           1
#> 2   143 25-07-1990           3
#> 3   165 23-03-1993          NA
#> 4   165 15-05-1995          NA
#> 5   174 30-12-2000          NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS          
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Europe/Rome                 
#>  date     2020-09-07                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  backports     1.1.9   2020-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  callr         3.4.3   2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  cli           2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  devtools      2.3.1   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  digest        0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.2   2020-08-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  generics      0.0.2   2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  knitr         1.29    2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  lifecycle     0.2.0   2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pillar        1.4.6   2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgbuild      1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  processx      3.4.3   2020-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ps            1.3.4   2020-08-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  purrr         0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rlang         0.4.7   2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.3     2020-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringi       1.4.6   2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  testthat      2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  tibble        3.0.3   2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  tidyselect    1.1.0   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  usethis       1.6.1   2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  utf8          1.1.4   2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  vctrs         0.3.4   2020-08-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  withr         2.2.0   2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  xfun          0.16    2020-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#> 
#> [1] /home/cl/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0
#> [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#> [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#> [4] /usr/lib/R/library
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `ave` + `subset`

```
subset(
  df,
  !ave(Negate(is.na)(category),
    PID,
    FUN = function(x) length(x) > 1 & any(x)
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  PID       date category
3 132 16-06-1994        1
4 143 25-07-1990        3
7 165 23-03-1993       NA
8 165 15-05-1995       NA
9 174 30-12-2000       NA
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(PID = c(123L, 123L, 132L, 143L, 154L, 154L, 165L, 
165L, 174L), date = c("22-04-1996", "25-02-2000", "16-06-1994",
"25-07-1990", "09-07-1993", "08-08-1998", "23-03-1993", "15-05-1995",
"30-12-2000"), category = c(2L, NA, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```